# simple way to convert View to Matcher<View> in espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

for ins, like following example, I hope first set listener and them work with espresso, so how to implement `toMatcher`

```
@Test
    public void testSpinner2() throws Exception {
        r.launchActivity(null);
        Spinner sp = (Spinner) r.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        sp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               //do smth
            }
        });

        onView(toMatcher(sp));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess following code can work:

```
public static Matcher<View> toMatcher(final View v) {
        return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
            @Override
            protected boolean matchesSafely(View item) {
                return item == v;
            }

            @Override

            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText(v.toString());
            }
        };
    }
```